# JS- FIlter the JSON accordingly

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

My Input is:

```
[
  {Value: "My_name", Status: "Done"},
  {Value: "My_lastName", Status: "Not_Done"}
]
```

The O/P expected is:

```
{
  Value: ["My_name", "My_lastName"]
  Status: ["Done", "Not_Done"]
}
```

Comment: its absolutely not clear what you want

Comment: What is the question? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please edit your question and try to be clear and descriptive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with `reduce` method:

```js
var data =[{Tag: "My_name", Clearance: "Done"},{Tag: "My_lastName", Clearance: "Not_Done"}];
result = data.reduce((acc,elem)=>{
  Object.entries(elem).forEach(([k,v])=>{
    acc[k] = acc[k] || [];
    acc[k].push(v);  
   })
  return acc;
},{});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: This Works Thank You!!

Comment: @Pats2281 Welcome, If this has resolved your issue, you can accept this as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
let input = [
    {Tag: "My_name", Clearance: "Done"},
    {Tag: "My_lastName", Clearance: "Not_Done"}
];
let output = {};

input.forEach((inputObj) => {
    Object.keys(inputObj).forEach((key) => {
        output[key] = output[key] || [];
        output[key].push(inputObj[key]);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use method `Object.entries` to [create enumerable string-keyed property [key, value] pairs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and then just use `reduce` method to fill array:

```
const arrayOfEntries = data.flatMap(s => (Object.entries(s)));
const result = arrayOfEntries.reduce((a, [k, v]) => 
    (a[k] = a[k] || [], a[k].push(v), a), {})
```

An example:

```js
const data =[{Tag: "My_name", Clearance: "Done"},
    {Tag: "My_lastName", Clearance: "Not_Done"}];

const arrayOfEntries = data.flatMap(s => (Object.entries(s)));
const result = arrayOfEntries.reduce((a, [k, v]) => 
    (a[k] = a[k] || [], a[k].push(v), a), {})
console.log(result)
```